# Taking Space Separated Row Inputs in a Two dimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

Im relatively new to programming and i was working with a problem that requires me to read space separated integers and input them into a two dimensional array but i dont seem to understand why I am not able to do so . any hint on possible approaches will be helpful

Eg. Input will look like this

2                  //FOR DIMENSION

2 3   //ROW1

4 5   // ROW 2

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    System.out.println("Enter Dimension of Matrix");
    int N= sc.nextInt();
    int[][] m=new int [N][N];
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {   System.out.println("Enter Elements of row "+ i);
       for(int j=0;j<N;j++ )
       {
        m[i]=sc.nextInt();
       }
    }
    System.out.println(m);
 }
}
```

I tested the above code  and got the following result on the console

**HelloWorld.java:16: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to int[]

            m[i]=sc.nextInt();**
                           ^

First of all,    I would   like to know is my thinking(approach) right?

Second, what are the possible ways to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Dimension of Matrix");

        int N = sc.nextInt();
        int[][] m = new int[N][N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Elements of row " + i);
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                m[i][j] = Integer.valueOf(sc.next());//replaced line with proper code
            }
        }
        sc.close();
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(m));//use this api to print arrays
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly,  I will read up on the two new things i was introduced  to i.e. Integer.valueof() adn Arrays.deepToString, Thank You

Comment: @Hardik Please accept the answer if u have got it!!

Answer (score 0):

m is a multidimensional array meaning you must specify m[i][?]. Like so

```
m[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
```

Your logic is a little off, you want to ask the user for input at row start i, and for the other columns j. Try this and happy coding :)

```
for (int i=0;i<N;i++){                  
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
        System.out.println("Enter Elements of row "+ i);
        m[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
    }
}

for (int i=0;i<N;i++){     
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
        System.out.print(m[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: this will take the input row-wise right ? can i do something like after a  new line character in the input, the program  input a new  row of the array?  @Aaron?

Comment: It will take values in filling each row in, at row start i and then the remaining columns j.
Could you explain that a bit more please?

Comment: what i meant to say was when im providing input at the console like 2 3 etc for the rows and when i provide the values for the next row after  2 3 the compiler encounters " /n" a new line character, so i thought the array inputs  could be manipulated by that as well though i am  really doubtful about this approach

Comment: That sounds far to complicated, it would probably take a while for myself to figure it out as I have never done anything like it before, it could be a case of asking the user at the start of every row do they want another one to be added, and if so appending the new row to the already existing array. As I said I an unsure of this.

Comment: i am convinced now  that this is a lengthy and an unnecessary approach, and its better to use it the the way @Imran as mentioned it in his answer below